# binarization of variable - experimental threshold choice. Is it good approach?

Tags: experiment-design, binary-data, discrete-data, k-nearest-neighbour, binning

I have some ratings averages values from 1 to 5(users were rating on 1,2,3,4,5 scale). I would like to split them into two classes: `credible`, `not-credible`. I know that respondents have a bias toward evaluating objects as credible to willingly.

```
distribution:
1   1%
2   2%
3   5%
4   77%
5   14%
```

I will then use this binary variable **as explained variable in model**, where I use about 20 features to train a classifier to predict whether an object is credible or not.

**QUESTION**:
Is it acceptable to experimentally choose a threshold by comparing how well the classifier(e.g k-NN) performs (F-measure) with different cut offs? Or is such an approach a data-leakage crime?:)

HOW DATA LOOKS LIKE:

(sorted)
[image]

(unsorted)
[image]

I also consider aggregation with use of min:

(sorted min)
[image]
(unsorted min)
[image]

Comment: It is very rarely a good idea to do things like this. It lowers power.

Comment: @PeterFlom set of evaluations is > 19k and after aggregation there are over 5k records.

Comment: OK, so power is not a problem. But this is still not generally a good idea. In fact, one of the few good reasons to lump categories would be low N in a category. You don't have that problem. Even 1% of 19,000 is plenty

Comment: I agree with Peter -- it seems like this reduction strategy loses valuable variance in the data.  The general idea, though, seems like it can work if repeated for several breaks in the data ([Here](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/~eibe/pubs/ordinal_tech_report.pdf) is a link to a paper on ordinal classification that does this).

Comment: Your term **explained variable** is unclear, I suppose it means outcome. Then this is an ordinal outcome variable, look into ordinl rebression (search this site, many good posts). And peruse the tag [tag:ordinal-data]